# FirebaseAnalytics LogEvent causes an ApplicationException g_app on Android

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am currently attempting to integrate Firebase Analytics into a Unity app for Android using Unity 2017.2.0f2 .NET4.6 (gradle build) and Firebase Unity SDK 4.2.0 (Analytics, Messaging and Remote Config).

It is currently working for the iOS Unity build. I have also successfully run the sample Android Unity project with Firebase Analytics, so I suspect there is a conflict with one or more of the third party libraries in the project. Helpshift resolves to v23 of the support libraries where as Firebase resolves to v25.

Here is a list of the third party libraries currently used:

- play-services-ads-lite-10.2.1.aar
- play-services-base-10.2.1.aar
- play-services-basement-10.2.1.aar
- play-services-tasks-10.2.1.aar
- hockeyapp-3.6.2.jar
- helpshift-2.8.1.aar
- amplitude-unity-2.13.3.jar
- support-annotations-24.0.0.jar
- support-v4-24.0.0.aar
- appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar
- cardview-v7-23.4.0.aar
- design-23.4.0.aar
- recyclerview-v7-23.4.0.aar
- support-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar

I have included the google-services.json file in the project and it looks to be generating the google-services.xml file with the appropriate app identifiers that match the Firebase Console.

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
void Start()
{   
    Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
        .LogEvent(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventLogin);
}
```

Here is the error I am getting when calling the LogEvent method:

```
E/Unity   (21111): Unable to find CoreFoundation
I/Unity   (21111): Firebase App initializing app com.company.appname (default 1).
I/Unity   (21111): Firebase Cloud Messaging API Initialized
E/Unity   (21111): ApplicationException: g_app
E/Unity   (21111):   at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent (System.String name) [0x00015] in <a84c2c17cb4f485088fe423edcd1bb5f>:0 
E/Unity   (21111):   at FirebaseLoginEvent.Start () [0x0000f] in <b9e7b735f2ee48bca490c781b0d990a3>:0
```

CoreFoundation shouldn't be in Android Unity builds according to https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=tr#!topic/firebase-talk/KiU3ZGMfRr8

Comment: Hello, Firebase engineer here.  I'm wondering whether you've reproduced the issue with our sample application https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/analytics/testapp ?  It would be great to narrow down potential conflicts with other plugins.  Also, if you post to firebase-talk@googlegroups.com perhaps you could share the entire logcat to aid debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have gathered the logcat output and posting in the firebase-talk group. I have not been able to reproduce in the sample app just yet. I will try adding in the other third party libraries one at a time to see if I can get any further information.

Comment: I spent a good chunk of the day adding each of the third party libraries back in one at a time. I kept each in a separate project, ensuring the individual projects worked, then copied over all the necessary files/libraries to the master project. I made sure I updated each of the support libraries accordingly and replaced older ones with the appropriate version to match. Long process, but I am not getting the error any more and the analytics are coming through to the dashboard.